# Bundle.putParcelable / getParcelable pair returns same object instance

Tags: android

I spent quite a while debugging a parcelable object acting weird in my application. Eventually I noticed, luckily, that an object sent via Bundle, in this case Fragment arguments, might be the exact same object I pass to it.

Consider following code snippet in which **r2** is not a copy, as I would have expected, but the same object **r** instead;

```
Rect r = new Rect();
Log.d("r", r.toString());     // Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("KEY", r);
Rect r2 = bundle.getParcelable("KEY");
r2.set(100, 100, 100, 100);
Log.d("r", r.toString());     // Rect(100, 100 - 100, 100)
Log.d("r2", r2.toString());   // Rect(100, 100 - 100, 100)
```

Now the question would be is there documentation about this behaviour somewhere? I'm running into this behaviour on Android 5.1 on Nexus 5 and would be interested in knowing is this something that existed already in API 1 for example and in which situations it'll return a copy instead via creator.

I'm sure there is but I fail to find correct search keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware that data you put into a bundle gets passed by a reference, not a copy of object so in the same class this will be the same object. On the other end (in your fragment, upon creating it) tough, the object is deserialized (unmarshalled) so this makes a copy of your original data.

Comment: This is pretty much what I'd like to understand better, when does Bundle get serialized? Especially for case where you pass Bundle as argument for Fragment.

Comment: Bundle is serialized after system destroy your instance or you pass your bundle between processes, as I understand. There is no reason to serialized it in each case.

Comment: I don't know exactly, but the source code here contains the answer . I think it's upoan the instantiation of fragment, but you should be aware that the copy is in the fragment, in the original class it's still a reference. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/Fragment.java

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at [`putParcelable` source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-0/android/os/Bundle.java#Bundle.putParcelable%28java.lang.String%2Candroid.os.Parcelable%29), you will find that this method only saves its reference (i.e. memory address).

If you would need to store a copy/clone of that object, you should copy/clone that object manually and then pass its reference to this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void More ...putParcelable(String key, Parcelable value) {
     unparcel();
     mMap.put(key, value);
     mFdsKnown = false;
 }
```

I don't know what magic does "unparcel()" method, but sources say that it is just Map with reference value.